# threejs raycast incorrect after group rotate

Tags: three.js

I take all mesh adding to a Three.group

when I rotation the Three.group it's really do it by view but inner mesh's value are incorrect (such as rotation & position etc...)

so after rotate to do raycast get incorrect result(actually befor rotate value   )

see code:

```
init{       
  _group = new THREE.Group();
   _scene.add(_group);

  _group.add(mesh1);
  _group.add(mesh2);
  _group.add(mesh.....);
 }

rotateClick{

  _group.rotateX(90 * Math.PI / 180)
}

dbClick{

   var intersections = rayCaster.intersectObjects( _group.children);
}
```

Comment: Try `_group.rotateX(..); _group.updateMatrixWorld();`

Comment: I had try updateMatrixWorld  . it's useless

Comment: How are you creating your raycaster? Also, are you expecting it to perform the raycast from your mouse position, or from a fixed position?

Comment: var mousePosition = new THREE.Vector3();

        mousePosition.x = ( event.offsetX / $(_editorCanvas).width() ) * 2 - 1;

        mousePosition.y = -( event.offsetY / $(_editorCanvas).height() ) * 2 + 1;

        mousePosition.z = 0.5;

        mousePosition.unproject(_camera);

        var origin = new THREE.Vector3().copy( _camera.position );
        var direction = new THREE.Vector3().copy( mousePosition.sub( _camera.position ) ).normalize();
        var rayCaster = new THREE.Raycaster( origin, direction );

Comment: @constant Code in comments is messy (as you can see). If you have a solution, please post it as an answer, where you can format it better.